# how to create PDF of dynamic contain using PHP script?

Tags: php, pdf-generation

Data is generated dynamically by using php, and displayed on browser in specified Design format; we need to generate PDF of that design format with dynamic data?

we have data in php Sting, want to convert data string in PDF.

```
$str="<html><body>
    <table width='100%'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
    <td width='3%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='98%' align='left'><br><img src='abs-path' border='0' alt='logo'>
    <br>
    <span class='style3'>Dear ".$name.",<br />
    <p>Many thanks for your Interest  
    <br />
    <br>
    Thanking You,<br />
    Secretariat <br>
    ".$addr."<br>

    </span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>";
```

we have tried pdf function but its not working, when we call image dynamically using php.
Also we have checked previously asked question regarding php-pdf, but still not able to solve the problem.
please help us to generate PDF using php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [online pdf generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971174/online-pdf-generation)

Answer (score 4):

You can you pdf file generator like [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/download.php) or fpdf ..

you just need to use readymade functions .. from tcpdf

Comment: +1. I've worked with FPDF. There is some labor, because you need to programmatically position your content, but it can be done, and the results are good.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a PDF-File using PHP is a task which is often done using a PHP-Library like:

- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

These two projects are the most common and both are up to date (support UTF-8 for example) and free. If you already use one of the above, please be more specific about what problem you're facing and what error-messages come up.

Both those library's use pure PHP to generate the PDF so you don't need to have "PDFlib" installed, which is used by the standard PDF-functions offered by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

At work we use [html2ps](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm), which has one big advantage over all the other solutions: You don't need to write PDF specific code but can re-use the HTML you generated anyway. Also, this is easier to debug and automatically spreads the contents on several pages.

Answer (score 1):

Hiii,
I feel its better to use the FPDF.It's available at www.fpdf.org

Answer (score 0):

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) has functions for PDF generation. You can't simply convert HTML to PDF though.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using the mpdf library, and it's quite nice (and free), you can use (a bit limited) html+css, ttf fonts, headers/footers, table of contents, index, and [more](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/).

[Examples](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/examples).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the mpdf it is best.. below is the url for the same
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php